# Media Server died., Camera Died, Error 100

Tags: android

It is running & recording video 3 to 4 Mints. Later it stops the video recording.
At Log file it shows. Media Server died, Camera dies, Error 100.

Problem with videorecorder, CamcorderProfile settings.

I am using Android Emulator & Nexus 7 AVD,

Video settings are:

```
private void StartVideoRecording(Camera videoCamera){

videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
videoRecorder.setCamera(videoCamera);               
videoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(cameraProfile.fileFormat); // look at ARTPWriter.cpp     //   videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(1); // look at ARTPWriter.cpp

videoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(cameraProfile.videoCodec);

videoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cameraProfile.videoFrameRate);
videoRecorder.setVideoSize(cameraProfile.videoFrameWidth, cameraProfile.videoFrameHeight);
videoRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(cameraProfile.videoBitRate);

videoRecorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/.Y3KVideo"); // File not used, but is needed for prepare to succeed.

videoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraViewSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
videoRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

try {
    videoRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
videoRecorder.start();  
}
```

CamcorderProflie settings:

```
private void configureCameraProfile() {
    cameraProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    cameraProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
    // cameraProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP;
    cameraProfile.fileFormat = 7; // RTP
    cameraProfile.videoFrameWidth = 176; // QCIF PAL
    cameraProfile.videoFrameHeight = 144;
    cameraProfile.videoBitRate = 128000;
    cameraProfile.videoFrameRate = 15;  //15

    Log.i(TAG, " bitrate=" + cameraProfile.videoBitRate + ",width=" + cameraProfile.videoFrameWidth + ",height=" + cameraProfile.videoFrameHeight);

}
```

Comment: As far as I know (although my experience with Android cameras is limited), if you customise the profile, it's not guaranteed to work. You should probably try `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QCIF` instead of `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW` and customising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Recorder May Work in Emulator.

But The settings You provided are Wrong.

please verify this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

and configure the settings as accordingly.